# Compiling a UWP app in a different language

Tags: uwp, resourcemanager

I have a UWP app that has a resource file for every language that we support.  If I change the language on the target machine to French (fr-FR) I correctly see all of our French strings loaded in the app.  This all works as expected.

However, in another place in our app, we load a particular file based on the "Language" property from the resource manager, like this:

```
var rc =   ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.GetSubtree("Files").GetValue("File.txt", ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView());

var lang = rc.Qualifiers.FirstOrDefault(q => q.QualifierName == "Language").QualifierValue;

// Get the file
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///" + lang + "/File.txt"));
```

On disk I have a different copy of "File.txt" in each language:

> en-US\File.txt 
>   fr-FR\File.txt 
>   etc.

However I can only ever get the en-US file to be read.  How do I compile our app in French, so the above snippet of code returns “fr-FR” for the “Language” qualifier?

Comment: With ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap you are getting access to .resw files. Do you have any .resw file in your project? Please describe it.

Comment: Yes the app has lots of .resw files, one for each language that we support.  It also has a props file that does the copying of the text files above.  The props file contains this:

<Content Include="$(FileDir)\en-us\File.txt">
      <Link>en-us\File.txt</Link>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="$(FileDir)\fr-fr\File.txt">
      <Link>fr-fr\File.txt</Link>
    </Content>

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to do something what is described in this article:
[[WinRT] How to get the language code actually used to resolve a resource](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2013/06/05/winrt-how-to-get-the-resolved-resource-language-code/)
It should work also with UWP applications.

But for my taste Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages is better. You can get language with something like:

```
var fr=Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages[0];
```